# Text won`t render using path in react rendered SVG. How can I use this textPath correctly?

Tags: reactjs, svg

Can anyone help me identify why my text is not rendering in the defined path #textPath03 ? The path is rendered as supposed, but when I put it inside a `<defs>` and try to use it, it doesn`t work.

```
    <svg version="1.1" height="700" width="700" viewBox="-5 -5 110 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" data-reactid="13">
  <defs data-reactid="14">
    <path id="#textPath03" d="M95,50 A45,45 0 0 0 50,5" data-reactid="15"></path>
  </defs>
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="black" data-reactid="16"></line>
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="0" stroke="black" data-reactid="17"></line>
  <path d="M90,50 A40,40 0 0 0 50,10" fill="none" stroke="green" data-reactid="18"></path>
  <use xlink:href="#textPath03" fill="none" stroke="red" data-reactid="19"></use>
  <text x="2" y="40%" font-size="20" data-reactid="20">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textPath03" data-reactid="21">Teste</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

This is a REACT rendered SVG.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path id contains an extraneous # character. Only the reference to the path should have that. Removing it fixes your example...

```html
<svg version="1.1" height="700" width="700" viewBox="-5 -5 110 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" data-reactid="13">
  <defs data-reactid="14">
    <path id="textPath03" d="M95,50 A45,45 0 0 0 50,5" data-reactid="15"></path>
  </defs>
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="black" data-reactid="16"></line>
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="0" stroke="black" data-reactid="17"></line>
  <path d="M90,50 A40,40 0 0 0 50,10" fill="none" stroke="green" data-reactid="18"></path>
  <use xlink:href="#textPath03" fill="none" stroke="red" data-reactid="19"></use>
  <text x="2" y="40%" font-size="20" data-reactid="20">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textPath03" data-reactid="21">Teste</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Omg! So simple! Thanks!!